# can you edit the "next" destination when using django's @login_required?

Tags: python, django

I can't find how to change the where it redirects to in the docs. I  lookined in my setting.py for a  LOGIN_URL thing to edit but I didnt find anything like that in there. Also just as a more broad thing. are there better django resources than the django docks? I can never get clear answers from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify a next parameter, then django will search for `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings, if it doesn't find this - it will default to `/accounts/profile/`.

So to override it, simply supply it in the URL: `login?next=/some/url`. `next` is the default, but you can call it something else, `login?after=/some/url`. If you do so, in your decorator you need specify what the field will be. `@login_required(redirect_field_name='after')`

You can specify a default redirect url in settings.py using `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, and then override it as needed.

There are no better docs than the ones that come with django, imo. Just make sure you are reading the docs *for the version of django you are using*. A lot of issues happen when you are reading the docs for the development version, but you are actually using the production release.

The current production release is **1.3.1**
The current development release is **1.4 RC 1**

You can tell the version of the documentation from the URL:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/**dev**/ = development version
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/**1.3**/ = production version

I always bookmark the topic index and the [table of contents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/contents/) and start my search from there.

A final tip - to quickly jump to the documentation of a particular method, use the django.me shortcut: http://django.me/render takes you directly to the correct page in the docs.

Comment: where do I edit next tho? in the template? or view or settings?

I just tried to add LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to my settings.py but yet it doesn't do anything when I try to load the page. It still tries to load the original page.

Comment: I ended up just defining accounts/login/ in the urlconf and with the signup from which works but i'm still curious as to how to change that stuff if you are willing

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py Define [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

Also , If you are using `django.contrib.auth.views.redirect_to_login` you can pass in the url as next which is a required argument.